# How to make an ArrayList of objects in Java with the ability to access their values

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist

so I'm working on a game in Java, and I'm a little confussed on how I should go about something. It's a Trading Card Game, kinda like Magic, and so for classes so far I have

- GameDriver
- Cards
- WolfCard
- TheLarionCard

It is my hope that I'll be able to have atleast 50 different types of card, each of which in their own class, so a little side question is, is this the best way? As for my problem:

I have the following code inside my GameDriver class:

```
ArrayList<Cards>  playerHand = new ArrayList<Cards>();
playerHand.add(new WolfCard());
playerHand.add(new TheLarionCard());
System.out.println(((Cards)playerHand.get(1)));
```

Each card extends Cards, and Cards extend GameDriver, The code above will print out something like:

```
TheLarionCard[panel0,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout]
```

But now, if I want to grab the health of say TheLarionCard, I thought I could just add .health to the last line like:

```
System.out.println(((Cards)playerHand.get(1).health));
```

But obviously I can't, what am I doing wrong here?

Any help is great! Thank you!

Comment: do all `Cards` inherit the `health` method from `Cards`, or does only `TheLarionCard` have a `health` method?

Comment: as pb2q stated, but is `health` a publicly assessable member?? (I'd have to be `.health()` to be a method ;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have three options:

1. You want each different type of card to have a `health` property. In this case, you can put that property into the parent class `Cards` and then it will be valid to ask for the property for any class that extends `Cards`. If the `Cards` class has a `health` data field, the code in your question will work.
2. You want only `TheLarionCard` to have a health property. In that case, your cast would have be:

   ```
   System.out.println(((TheLarionCard)playerHand.get(1).health));
   ```

   This way, the compiler has knows to look in the `TheLarionCard` class for the health property, not the `Cards` class.
3. You don't actually need the individual card classes to be subclasses of `Cards`. If there's no really compelling reason you've done it that way, you could have all cards be part of the `Cards` class and their different types (TheLarionCard, WolfCard, etc) could be designated by a data field. For example:

   ```
   public class Card {
       String type;

       public Card(String inType) {
           this.type = inType;
       }

       public String toString() {
           return "This is a " + type;
       }
   }
   ```

   This way if you want the different cards to behave differently, you can check their `type` value and assign different behaviors based on its value, e.g.

   ```
   public void awesomeMethod() {
       if ("TheLarionCard".equals(type)) {
           // execute TheLarionCard code
       } else if ("WolfCard".equals(type)) {
           // execute WolfCard code
       }
   }
   ```

   This is a simplified version of the [Abstract Factory Pattern](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=128) design that some of the other answers were talking about, so if you're new to interfaces you could try it this way to see if the structure works, then add interfaces later.

Answer (score 1):

Define an interface or abstract method `getHealth()` method in `Cards`, that must be implemented by `WolfCard` and `TheLarionCard`. Then, you can do `playerHand.get(1).getHealth()`.

For instance:

```
public abstract class BaseCard {
  protected int health;

  public abstract int getHealth();
}

public class WolfCard extends BaseCard {
  private int wolfHealthBoost;  

  public int getHealth() {
    return health + wolfHealthBoost;
  }
}

public class TheLarionCard extends BaseCard {
  public int getHealth() {
    return health;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a little further? I've not used interfaces before, unless I have and I didn't know that was what they were.

Comment: @JeremySayers: I've added a small usample using an abstract base class.

Comment: Thank you, your answer, answers my question perfectly, but now I'm a bit skeptical if this is the best way to do it, for instance, how would I go about grabbing random cards to fill a deck? Should I be doing one class, that creates the cards inside of it?

Comment: Yes, you can create a `DeckBuilder` that has a `List` of all possible cards, and then randomly takes, say, 52 elements from that list to create a desk.

Comment: What I ended up doing what having the Driver class and the Card class, and inside of the Card constructor I declare health strength etc, so that in the driver class I can just do: library.add(new Card("Iron Hedgehog", 2, 2, 2)); bam! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you have the getter for the health attribute in those classes, private attributes can't be accessed from outside the class.

Just make a new method, getHealth(), that returns the health attribute, and then append it after the dot at the last line.

BTW, you don't have to cast the Cards class if you already defined the ArrayList with that stereotype.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need interfaces or even such a complex variety of classes. I'm guessing all of your Cards have generally similar behavior. They are of a certain type, can do a specific action, can have actions and/or effects happen onto them etc. So you only need one Cards class for this, and in it have all the fields and methods that manage those generic states/actions.

Then you can make separate classes that inherit from Cards class (which btw, it's better to rename to just "Card"),  like if you have effect type cards (such as a MTG Mana Flare or Hideous Visage equivalents) and then you also have creature cards (like MTG's Shivan Dragon or Dragon Whelp) you can make classes such as EffectCard which might have it's own fields like "duration" and "affectedTypes" and then use it to make ManFlare instances, Hideous Visage instances, etc. Also make a CreatureCard with stuff like hitpoints, firstStrike, etc. and make ShivanDragon instances and DragonWhelp instances from it.

Also don't be afraid of composition. Instead of subclassing/making extra classes for each card, make a simpler hierarchy like the one above and pass it "command" or "action" classes which dictates the more specific details. Like the FirstStrike instance of the EffectCard class could be initialized with an "action" instance that tells it specifically how to affect a CreatureCard instance, the ShivanDragon instance of the CreatureCard class would have an action telling it how it's attack can be increased by utilizing Red Lands cards, etc.